# python: list assignment index out of range [sieve of erathostenes]

Tags: python

I have this class to be called from the main method, which finds all the prime numbers in a list by implementing the Sieve of Erathostenes. However at the line

```
nums[j] = 0
```

I am getting the error mentioned above:

> list assignment index out of range

This is my code:

```
class Prime:

def is_prime(self, num):
    chk = False
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num % i == 0:
            chk = True
    return chk

def sieve_of_erathos(self, num):
    nums = []
    for i in range(2, num):
        nums.append(i)
    for i in range(2, num):
        if i != 0:
            for j in range(i+1, num):
                if j % i == 0:
                    nums[j] = 0
    primes = []
    for i in range (2, num):
        if nums[i] != 0:
            primes.append(nums[i])
    return primes
```

Comment: this is the problem for j in range(i+1, num): i guess

Comment: Your `is_prime` is not correct , it returns `True` for `12`, I think you chk default must be True` and  you should `False` it in loop and use `break` after that

Comment: @Arman the boolean output is then processed by the main function and the output is done accordingly. In the case of 12, the output is that it is NOT prime.

Comment: In that case, you should rename it to `is_not_prime` (or something) to make it less confusing.

Comment: BTW, `if i != 0:` is redundant since `2 <= i < num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you fill your Array with range(2,num).

This creates num-2 spaces in the array which means you can only call `nums[num-3]` .

In

```
for j in range(i+1, num):
            if j % i == 0:
                nums[j] = 0
```

You call `nums[num-1]` so use

```
for i in range(2, num+2):
        nums.append(i)
```

instead. Then everything should work